# Is it necessary to complete recitation of entire Qur'an in taraweeh?

Tags: quran, ramadan, taraweeh

A few queries that I have in my mind about `taraweeh` prayers during `Ramadan`.

1. Is it necessary to complete recitation of the entire Qur'an during the night prayers?
2. How about if I complete the recitation of the Qur'an "offline" during the daytime, so to speak, and just recite some short surahs in the night prayers?

Jazakallahu khairan.

Answer (score 2):

To read the Quran in the Salat, and out of it in Ramadan, is something praised/praiseworthy.  But in the Taraweeh (and in the other Salat), you may read as much as you can, even if it is a short Surah, and if you are an Imam then be conscious of those who are following.  Lastly, it is not ***necessary*** for you to complete the entire Quran in The salat.  Also it is Sunnah on the Imam to read the whole Quran once in Taraweeh during Ramadan (and this is the position taken by the Hanabalah and the majority of the Hanafiyah), but if he cannot then it is ok.

> فَاقْرَءُوا مَا تَيَسَّرَ مِنَ الْقُرْآنِ
>
> so recite what is easy [for you] of the Qur'an

[Surat Al Muzzamil Ayah 20](http://quran.com/73/20)

Sources, and links for more information (in Arabic): [this](http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/66504), [this](http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/65572), and [this](http://www.binbaz.org.sa/mat/45210).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it is _sunnah_ for the imam to read the whole Qur'an?