# Rapid Recitation of Quran during Taraweeh Prayer

Tags: quran, hadith, hadith-interpretation, quran-recitation, taraweeh

Here in India, 
While offering the taraweeh prayer the Noble Quran is recited really fast in order to just complete it by the time the month gets over. I really dont think that this type of recitation is of any use when the main purpose is not to ponder over the meaning of the amazing Book but to simply finish it in a month's time. Is this even permissible or not ? How did the Prophet (peace be upon him ) and the  Companions ( may Allah be pleased with them ) recite it during Taraweeh ? Please back your answer with Quranic verses and Sahih Hadith.
JazaakAllahu khairan.

Comment: I pointed at the fact that earlier Muslims used to complete the quran as much as they can and it's not a sunnah to complete it rather than to recite it in a correct way in my anyser on your question http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8234/is-it-necessary-to-complete-recitation-of-entire-quran-in-taraweeh?rq=1

Comment: Many Turkish Imam's in the country i live in only read the 10-20 last Surahs of the Quran each night in the Tarawih prayer, maybe they may recite some well known verses as the last verses of surat al-Baqara or ayat al-Kursi etc.

Comment: This is apparently an issue in which there is difference of opinion. As-written, it is simply going to attract more argument and debate, which is not what this site is for.

Answer (score 3):

It's forbidden to read/recite Quraan in haste.  Allah says:

> **"Move not your tongue with it, to hasten with it."**

([al-Qiyaamah 75:16](http://legacy.quran.com/75/16))

The purpose of recitation is to understand the words and ponder over them. Not just to recite for the sake of reciting:

> **"A book which We have sent down to you, full of blessings, that they may ponder over its Verses, and that men of understanding may remember"**

([Saad 38:29](http://legacy.quran.com/38/29))

> **And those who disbelieved said, "Why wasn't the Qur'an sent down all at once?" Thus, that We may strengthen thereby your heart. And We have recited it distinctly.**

([al-Furqaan 25:32](http://legacy.quran.com/25/32))

> **"Or add to it, and recite the Qur'an with a measured recitation."**

([al-Muzzammil 73:4](http://legacy.quran.com/73/4))

Therefor, one's recitation should be measured and distinct. Not so fast that one cannot distinguish between two separate words or sentences.

Answer (score 2):

First of all it is not compulsory to finish the Qur'an in one month through the tarawih prayer. If done properly then there is great goodness in it without a doubt. But when we seek goodness from Allah subhana wa ta 'ala then it should be according to His rules as defined in the Qur'an and Sunnah based upon the understanding of our Salaf(pious predecessors) and not based upon the understanding or logic or even norms of the people around us, even if we be the only one on correct path and the entire world is going in different direction all together. We should remember that no one will be able to help us in the Akhirah and we will be accounted alone and we will be asked for each and every action and our deeds and from where did we learn them and on whose understanding did we performed them.

As for reciting the Qur'an in such speed is in clear violation of Makhraj and Tajweed rules, and these rules of Tajweed are not man made rather these rules were taught to Jibraeel aleihi salam by Allah subhana wa ta ala Himself and in turn Jibraeel aleihis salam taught it to our noble Prophet Muhammad sallallahu aleihi wa sallam. In Arabic even a slightest of variation changes the meaning to a difference of heaven and hell, not just in terms of vowel but in terms of vocal vibrations of sound and also elongation of vowels. For example in the first chapter Surah Fatihah if we recite Alhamdu normally without proper Tajweed(then it means that rags or torn clothes are for Allah) and if we recite it by exhaling good amount of air out of our lungs and the voice should come from chest and follow proper Tajweed rules then it means that Praise be to Allah. See the huge variation in just from where the voice is coming. So do you think that proper tajweed rules are being followed during such recitations?

for more info on Tarawih please go thought the Authentic narrations given in the below link
http://sunnah.com/search/?q=tarawih

Comment: Great answer I must say ... wouldn't tick mark (although i have upvoted it ) since I am waiting for more responses

Comment: To make your answer more useful it would be nice if you please added the full link to your references.

Comment: Your answer requires evidence for your claims of tajweed.

Comment: @Sayyid those can be found in your answer, at least to some extent!

Answer (score 1):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions,

As there are three types of recitation

Tahqeeq ([slow](http://www.abouttajweed.com/al-faa~7_128.mp3)),

Tadweer ([medium](http://www.abouttajweed.com/alfaa~9_128.mp3)),

Hadr ([fast](http://www.abouttajweed.com/al-faa~8_128.mp3)).

Tahqeeq is reciting the Quran slowly with pondering over the meanings and observing full rules of Tajweed.Tadweer is reciting in a medium level not very slowly ,not very fast but observing rules of tajweed and hadr is quick recitation usually done in tarawih but has to be done with observing rules of tajweed.

So if tajweed rules are followed and letters are recited in an appropriate manner with proper characteristics and Makhraj(point of articulation) without change of meaning and lahn (mistakes) then this type of recitation is permissible and considered as Hadr recitation.

Well Scholars has mentioned that it is Sunnah to complete entire Quran in Tarawih ,it is not fardh so if someone doesnt he is not a sinner but he would miss those rewards,Also please see this fatwa :

> *Reciting the entire Qur’an (khatm) once in Tarawih prayers is an important Sunna that has been practiced by the Muslims throughout the
>   centuries. As such, it should not be abandoned in the various Mosques
>   where there has been a tradition of completing the Qur’an, even if the
>   time for Eisha is late. However, if one experiences genuine hardship
>   in reciting or listening to the entire Qur’an, it would be permitted
>   for him/her to recite short Surahs or verses from the Qur’an during
>   Tarawih prayers.Imam al-Haskafi (Allah have mercy on him), the
>   renowned Hanafi jurist, states: “Completing the Qur’an (khatm) once
>   [in Tarawih prayers] is Sunna, completing it twice is virtuous, and
>   completing it thrice is even better. As such, its completion should
>   not be abandoned due to people’s laziness. However, it is stated in
>   ‘Al-Ikhtiyar’ that it is better in our times to recite an amount that
>   does not burden people…” The commentator of Haskafi’s work, Imam Ibn
>   Abidin (Allah have mercy on him) explains further by saying that the
>   majority of Imams including Abu Hanifa (Allah have mercy on him)
>   consider completing the Qur’an to be an important Sunna. However, he
>   says, certain rulings change based on the needs and interests of
>   people, and thus in our times [Ibn Abidin’s], it is better to recite
>   an amount that will not lead to people staying away from the
>   congregation, because having a larger congregation is superior to
>   lengthy recitation."
>   ([Source](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2011/08/08/is-it-obligatory-to-complete-the-entire-quran-during-tarawih-prayers/))

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: +1 for the explanation on the recitation types. Personally I once prayed tarawih behind a Turkish Imam and he recited very fast, so that me as an Arabic speaker could make out wrong pronunciation and meanings, after explaining my point of view that was the last time to pray tarawih at this mosque for me. As according my knowledge a prayer behind an Imam who recite like that would be void.

Comment: @Sayyid JazakAllah for letting me know your concern.This is Sunni Hanafi view.