# Should I pray behind Imam that recites too fast and skips words?

Tags: salat, taraweeh

At the place where I live (in my masjid), imam do prayers very fast. To give you an idea we finish Isha prayer + Tarawih + Witr prayer in about 30 minutes. He's going that fast that he sometimes skips some words in Al Fatiha. Plus there is no space to recite subhaneke so I need to recite it while he recites Al Fatiha.

Two days ago I spoke with him and asked if it's possible to slow it down so I can recite subhaneke. He told me to recite it while he's reciting Al Fatiha and to don't worry because he's taking all responsibilities. He said the reason why he's doing it is that there are 90% old people and they hardly can take a wudu. So it's basically to ease them. The congregation is really small about 20 people at max. What's strange as I know no one complained about it. I said ok and didn't want to argue because of the next reasons:

1. I started to pray about 2 months ago
2. The Imam I'm speaking about knows almost whole Quran, he's a few pages to became hafiz.
3. He's imam over 5 years in this masjid
4. He has an amazing voice and he's able to recite like Arabic is his native language. I listened to his youtube videos (I won't share it here, I don't want to reveal his identity), it's really beautiful and it's really sad that he does not do even close to that on prayers.

**It's not just Taraweeh I have been on other prayers and it's the almost same speed, no way you can recite subhaneke.**

I'm in a big doubt, I just prayed zuhr at home. My second option is going to the main Masjid in my city which is 1.2 kilometers from my home. I decided from now on to go there too Taraweeh. Prayers there are way slower.

**The thing is I don't feel that I will be able to go on most of the prayers there, I'm I doing a mistake if I'm praying at home for the above reasons?**

Comment: Relevant: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31478/rapid-recitation-of-quran-during-taraweeh-prayer/31499#31499

Comment: Do you have an answer on this already? Because i have the same problem as you now. Let me know