# How long is the Taraweeh prayer usually?

Tags: ramadan, sawm, taraweeh

I know Taraweeh prayer is done after the Isha/evening prayer, but how many rakats is it usually? What separates it from the tahajjud prayer, which is also done at night as well?

Comment: There's no usuall time, as it depends on the Imam and local costums etc.

Comment: Here one of many relevant posts https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8234/13438

Comment: Also relevant https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31422/reading-the-quran-in-ramadan/31427#31427

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different opinions on the prescribed rakahs for Taraweh, but the most common opinion is of 20 rakahs.

In mosques they usually<sup>1</sup> attempt to complete the whole Quran within the month of Ramadhan, so they recite a little more than a Juz (1/30th part) of the Quran each night. It may take a few hours depending on the speed of the reciter. People who don't offer the whole 20 rakahs usually leave after 8 or 12.

For reference see this [video stream](https://youtu.be/-N2L-uZeaEc?t=25m7s) of Tarawih in the Masjid ul Haram and [this query on islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/9036) on the opinions about the number of Rakahs.

---

1 <sub>As Medi1Saif mentioned in the comments. This may vary from place. Some schools of thought consider it the *Sunnah* to complete the whole Quran during the Taraweh ( [source-1](https://archive.org/stream/IslamicJurisprudenceAccordingToTheFourSunniSchoolsAlFiqhalaAlMadhahibAlArbaah#page/n481/mode/2up) , [source-2](https://islamqa.info/en/66504)).</sub>

Comment: All you are quoted are practices, which have no clear backup in the quran and sunnah. Imam's are asked to take care of their ma'mums. There's no evidence for completing the quran in taraweeh. I know of Imams whom only recite a few verses or short surahs during taraweeh, no matter if it falls in summer or winter. So on the whole the answer of مجاهد i've linked in my comment has a better backup.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I understood the question to be asking what to expect in practice in an average congregation in a mosque and not what is minimally prescribed in fiqh.

Comment: I know but this is simply hard to answer as it is the decision of the Imam. I also know of mosques where they complete the quran twice once in thajjud and once in taraweeh, others recite 5 ahzaab in taraweeh it is depending on people, location etc. there's no standard. The basis is there must be a gap (for sleeping) between taraweeh and tahajjud.